# (Node.js) Discord bot won't ready

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

This is by far the weirdest problem I ran in so far developing my Discord bot. This bot uses Discord.js.
I use a simple `client.on('ready', () => {})   client.login(<token goes here>)` thing, the default. But somehow, the console doesn't give me an error, nor any logs, but it also doesn't do anything. Please take a look at my code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { prefix, token } = require('./config.json');
const client = new Discord.Client();
//-------------------------------------------
const UserDataModel = require(`./data/userdata`);
const InventoryModel = require(`./data/inventory`);
const { connect } = require(`mongoose`);

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('Bot online!');
});

client.on('message', async (message) => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(' ');
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
    //more code down below
}

(async () => {
    await connect(`mongodb://localhost/discord-bot`, {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useFindAndModify: false,
        useUnifiedTopology: true
    });
    client.login(token);
});
```

As you can see, I use MongoDB for the data storage. Maybe it is a config problem, but I don't know how to fix such problems after much time spent on searching around. Any type of help is much appreciated! If additional code is needed, comment which part you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an anonymous which never executes

```js
(async () => {
    await connect(`mongodb://localhost/discord-bot`, {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useFindAndModify: false,
        useUnifiedTopology: true
    });
    client.login(token);
})();
```

Should work

Comment: Thank you! It worked. Can you explain how these anonymous things work, so I can fix this type of problems if I come across another one?

Comment: I guess we'll never know...